# Refresh/redraw a div without animations and keypress working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm currently using jQuery to try and refresh a div without completely refreshing the page. So far I am doing it with

```
$("#game").load(" #game > *");
```

This keeps my animation and prevents a duplicate div creation but any key input is then broken. Here is my HTML div

```
<div class="game" id="game">
    <div id="dino"></div>
    <div id="cactus"></div>
</div>
```

I want to refresh the game div ideally. Is this possible to do? Or does the entire page need to be reloaded? Thanks.

Edit: I am using the code from this repository: https://github.com/mdbootstrap/knowledge-base/tree/main/JS/games/dino-game

I have not made any changes regarding it.

https://codepen.io/michaeljgilson/pen/MWBjdJE

Edit: I've tried this as well with no luck

```
    $( "#game" ).load(window.location.href + " #game" );
```

Comment: It seems like you are missing some context here. We have no info regarding what is inside the game div. We also have no info as to why a key input would matter here. Try creating a code pen or provide a lot more info about this "game" you are building.

Comment: You may have asked an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info) (about your proposed solution instead of your actual problem). Please revise to ask about what you're trying to accomplish instead.

Comment: @user3821538 I updated the post, sorry about that. My main goal is to have the game reset when you lose instead of reloading the whole page.